# Driveway eroding

Tags: repair, driveway

I have a gully 2-3 ft wide and about 2ft deep running down the side of my drivewsy down near the bottom of a hill. Someone told me to put some bags of unopened cement in these gullies . Will this work?

Comment: We will need a lot more information such as what material your driveway is. Pictures also go a long way

Comment: What is the intent? Are you trying to slow down the flow or redirect it? Are you intending to make a dam? Aren't you concerned about where the water will go if you restrict flow? Please give more info.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use concrete mix not cement. Cement is more expensive and has nothing to hold it together it will form a block but is much more expensive. I have done this many times over the years. I place the bags tightly together then poke holes in the top of the bags and wet them down this starts the block forming and as time goes on it will become solid. I use the light duty bags as they are cheaper and work fine.